# Rails simple model attributes not saved to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a small Rails 3 app that reads data from the Steam API. What I am seeing is that the model attributes for any ActiveRecord model I create are not saved to the database nor are they output if I `debug` them.

Here my sample model

```
class NonPlayableApp < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name, :steam_id
  attr_accessible :name, :steam_id
end
```

With the migration file being:

```
class CreateNonPlayableApps < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :non_playable_apps do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :steam_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Here are few tests with the Rails console, I get the same results when I try them in a controller and `inspect` or `yaml` the model:

```
irb(main):001:0> temp = NonPlayableApp.new( steam_id: 33333, name: "Testing" )
=> #<NonPlayableApp id: nil, name: nil, steam_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0> temp.steam_id
=> 33333
irb(main):003:0> temp.name
=> "Testing"
irb(main):004:0> temp.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (4.0ms)  INSERT INTO "non_playable_apps" ("created_at", "name", "steam_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Fri, 26 Feb 2016 19:40:37 UTC +00:00], ["name", nil], ["steam_id", nil], ["updated_at", Fri, 26 Feb 2016 19:40:37 UTC +00:00]]
   (8.8ms)  commit transaction
=> true
irb(main):005:0> temp.steam_id
=> 33333
irb(main):006:0> temp
=> #<NonPlayableApp id: 64, name: nil, steam_id: nil, created_at: "2016-02-26 19:40:37", updated_at: "2016-02-26 19:40:37">
irb(main):007:0> temp2 = NonPlayableApp.first
  NonPlayableApp Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "non_playable_apps".* FROM "non_playable_apps" LIMIT 1
=> #<NonPlayableApp id: 64, name: nil, steam_id: nil, created_at: "2016-02-26 19:40:37", updated_at: "2016-02-26 19:40:37">
irb(main):008:0> temp2.steam_id
=> nil
irb(main):009:0> temp2.name
=> nil
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`attr_accessor :name, :steam_id` overrides the setter and getter methods that Rails automatically generates for that attributes.

Just delete the `attr_accessor :name, :steam_id` line from your model.

Comment: This works, thanks. I guess Rails takes the list of attributes for each model from the table schema?

Comment: That's right, Rails generates getter and setter methods for each column found in the database table.

Comment: Why do you use Rails 3 if you develop the app now? Rails 5 beta is out already.

Comment: @spickermann I am coming from Rails 3 and jumping into building a Rails 5 (beta 3) API application: I also had the same issue where I had 'attr_accessor' in the Model and wasn't able to save a record from the Rails console until I removed 'attr_accessor'. Can you give a URL to give further information about this b/c I still don't understand. I thought one needed to create getters/setters in order to save Model data to the database or use attr_accessible which is no longer in use for Rails 4 and onward.

Comment: @spickermann I haven't declared any getters/setters in my Model object and yet when I run in Rails console `n = Cals::Person.new` it lists the object's properties. How does it know the properties of Cals::Person model?

Comment: @Chris: An `ActiveRecord` model reads the column names and types from the corresponding database table and creates getter and setter methods automatically (Rails' magic yeah!) on the fly. When you declaire a `attr_accessor` then you override the methods that were created by Rails and the whole magic doesn't work anymore. Whereas `attr_accessable` was a security feature that was removed in favor of [`StrongParameters`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

Comment: what getter and setter methods are you referring to that rails generates? besides callbacks and validation, attr_accessor is visible and sometimes required for testing otherwise you get method undefined

Comment: @RidhwaanShakeel When you have a database column `name` (or `steam_id`) like the OP then Rails will generate a `name` getter and a `name=` setter method automatically. In such cases defining `attr_accessor :name` wold override the generated method and you would not be able to set the database attributes anymore. In those cases (because the OP had this issue) using `attr_accessor` would never work.